# Loading sas files into netezza on Aginity

Tags: sas, netezza, enterprise-guide, aginity

I'm trying to load data with over 50 million records into Netezza using Aginity. The problem is that my data table is a sas format with extension .sas7bdat that I open on SAS Enterprise Guide. So currently I have a script that transforms the sas files into csv file that I can load into Netezza.

Is there a way that I can load these sas files directly into Netezza without having to convert it to csv? Does Aginity provide an easy method of doing this? Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how can do it Netezza using Aginity but it very simple and easy in SAS enetrprise guideAs You said you have SAS eneterprise guide, please check whether you have SAS/ACCESS to Netezza. To check whether you have an SAS/ACCESS to Netezza then you can use below code in SAS enterprise guide

```
proc setinit; run;
```

If you have SAS/Access to Netezza, which probaly you may have it. To code this in SAS Enterprise guide is very easy and you can easily emulate in SAS eneterprise, by using examples shown in the link.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003181092.htm

Byusing libname statement in your SAS enterprise guide and can use proc append or proc sql and also use bulk load as as shown in above link.

Comment: you mean setinit right? not setint?...just making sure because Im new to this

Comment: I don't have SAS/ACCESS to Netezza, do you know how I can get it?

Comment: checker whether you have odbc to netezza. this piece of software needs to be purchased and I am not sure, how can you get it

Comment: I have odbc to netezza since I needed it for aginity but Netezza is not visible in SAS Enterprise guide

Comment: can you try talking to team, which handles SAS at your location and see if anyone has the access and also request access for you.

Comment: Be sure to use the BULKLOAD option when uploading. [Undocumented SAS feature: Bulkloading to Netezza with ODBC interface](https://heuristicandrew.blogspot.com/2016/02/sas-bulkload-netezza-odbc.html) Andrew Ziem, Feb 2016

Comment: @Kiran so I don't have the Netezza driver but I am able to load SAS files to Netezza using ODBC driver. Is there a negative aspect in doing it through odbc?

Comment: @Kiran sorry by driver, what I really meant was engine. So I use a libname with the ODBC connection to connect to netezza. There would be no performance issue in doing this?